# axios patch not working in chrome

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to update some articles on a drupal site using React axios. GET and POST requests work, but I can't get PATCH to work. Sending the PATCH request through Postman works just fine. I get the following error using axios:

> Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in
>   preflight response.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
  editState(nid, value){
    let node = {
      "type":[{"target_id":"article","target_type":"node_type"}],
      "body":[{"value": value}]
    }
    let config = {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }
    axios.patch('http://localhost:8888/d8restapi/node/' + nid + '?_format=json',node,config)
    .then((success) => {
      console.log(success);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Here are my OPTIONS request Headers:

- Request URL:http://localhost:8888/d8restapi/node/16?_format=json
- Request Method:OPTIONS
- Status Code:200 OK
- Remote Address:[::1]:8888
- Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
- Response Headers
- view source
- Allow:GET, POST, DELETE, PATCH
- Cache-Control:must-revalidate, no-cache, private
- Connection:Keep-Alive
- Content-language:en
- Content-Length:0
- Content-Type:application/json
- Date:Fri, 03 Nov 2017 21:08:24 GMT
- Expires:Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
- Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=98
- Server:Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 PHP/7.0.10
- mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2h DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9
- Perl/v5.24.0
- X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
- X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
- X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
- X-Generator:Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)
- X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.10
- X-UA-Compatible:IE=edge
- Request Headers
- view source
- Accept:*/*
- Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
- Accept-Language:en,en-US;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6,fi;q=0.4
- Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
- Access-Control-Request-Method:PATCH
- Connection:keep-alive
- Host:localhost:8888
- Origin:http://evil.com/
- Referer:http://localhost:3000/
- User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6)
- AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100
  Safari/537.36
- Query String Parameters
- view source
- view URL encoded
- _format:json

Edit: Tested with Firefox and it works, but it doesn't work in Chrome! Have emptied caches and restarted and done a hard reload to no avail.

Edit 2: Problem solved. I installed another CORS plugin in Chrome. The following works in case anyone is facing the same problem with other CORS plugins:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with the Drupal site not allowing PATCH although it's weird that it works in Postman. Can you check the OPTIONS request made to the same URL before the PATCH request in the browser dev tools and add the response to your question?

Comment: Updated question with OPTIONS request.

Comment: Strangely it also works in Firefox, but not Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried exporting the request from Chrone into Postman? You can right click the request in the network tab and select "Copy as cURL", then import itas plain text in Postman.

Comment: I'm only seeing the OPTIONS request in the network tab.

Comment: Is it failing at the OPTIONS request or refusing to make the PATCH request? Also, what happens if you spoof the method (ie make the method POST but include a _method field with a value of PUT)?

Comment: Problem solved! I installed another CORS plugin in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced exactly the same thing. Like you, just the combination of react, axios and chrome didn't work.

I solved the issue by changing my CORS chrome extension to this one:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/access-control-allow-cred/hmcjjmkppmkpobeokkhgkecjlaobjldi

Answer (score 0):

I've similar experience on serverless and reactjs. First I thought the issue is on serverless CORS configuration but it's actually I forgot to put

```
e.preventDefault()
```

when submitting the form. As a result, the request is cancelled because the page is loaded although the response is not returned yet.