# Form submission canceled because the form is not connected - VueJs in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, forms, vue.js, form-submit, code-inspection

I want to test the response in the console log. I am using the google inspect tool. I can't see any response in **Network>>XHR**. But I have seen that "*Form submission canceled because the form is not connected*" in **console**. The sample screen [inspect tool screen](https://prnt.sc/12zknu3) I can't trace the problem actually where. I am following a course video about laravel and vue. Thanks in advance for your time.
**Form**

```
<form v-if="editing" @submit.prevent="update">
    <div class="form-group">
    <textarea rows="10" v-model="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button @click="editing = false">Update</button>
    <button @click="editing = false">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

**in Controller**

```
if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Answer updated!',
                'body_html'
            ]);
        }
```

**Vue.JS**

```
<script>

export default {
 props: ['answer'],

 data () {
  return {
   editing: false,
   body: this.answer.body,
   bodyHtml: this.answer.body_html,
   id: this.answer.id,
   questionId: this.answer.question_id
  }
 },

 methods: {
  update () {
   axios.patch(`/questions/${this.questionId}/answers/${this.id}`, {
    body: this.body
   })
   .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.editing = false;
   })
   .catch(err => {
    console.log("something went wrong");
   });
  }
 }       
}
</script>
```

The form is by default hidden. It appears only when clicking on the Edit button. The only problem is to submit the form. ErrorMessage: Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Comment: I think the code is here is alright. Probably a problem with the chrome setup.
I installed an extension and run it. Later I have removed the extension. I can see the expected result in the chrome dev tool. I found it helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103184/axios-patch-not-working-in-chrome

Answer (score 1):

You have `v-if="editing"` in your form set to false. It should be true, because form has to exist on submit. You are removing your form from DOM. Also move `this.editing` to `finally()` block in axios call.

Comment: I have used a button to make editing=true
<a @click.prevent="editing = true" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">Edit</a>

Comment: In your question you have editing = false. You can check it in browser with Vue Devtools.

Comment: yes, in data property editing=false, as by default for is hidden. When the edit button clicked, only the form worked. Please check my comment .

Comment: I suggest you should remove ```v-if="editing"``` just for a try to check if there is a bug.

Comment: I found it is working now.
First I tried to move the update() method call from the <form> tag to first button tag. Then, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form v-show="editing" @submit.prevent="update">
    <div class="form-group">
</form>
```

use v-show="editing" directive